# Rails Scaffolding [controller]#new crashing server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scaffolding, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Continuing with my Rails Library Management App, I learnt about scaffolds and thought that it would give me ample framework to re-work upon. The thing is, that although scaffolds are being generated and everything, they aren't working properly. Rather, they aren't working at all.

When I access to **http://localhost/[controller-name]**, It shoots up a webpage that says **Listing [controller-name]** all fine. But when i click on new button or navigate to **http://localhost/[controller-name]/new**, the server crashes without an error.

**P.S.**

While trying things, I noticed that although,

```
$ rails generate scaffold person name:string identity:integer DOB:date
```

works just fine,

```
$ rails generate scaffold student name:string id_number:integer class:integer section:string issued:date returned:date fine:integer reissued:date
```

doesn't?

**P.P.S.**

The real problem is, accessing the action "student#new" does not only **NOT** work, but also crashes my server (yeah no exiting WEBrick). All I can provide are the messages that appear at the end:

```
Started GET "/assets/students.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-05 12:20:19 +0530


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-05 12:20:19 +0530


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-05 12:20:19 +0530


Started GET "/students/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-05 12:20:21 +0530
Processing by StudentsController#new as HTML
```

Comment: Do you have the `routes` set up in `routes.rb`?

Comment: doesn't scaffolding do that for me?

Comment: Calling a column `class` is almost certainly a bad idea. Not sure if that's related but try changing the name of that column.

Comment: No routes set up as of now. All my routes.rb has is: `resources :students`

Comment: Yes. Nevermind :) Try @Dave suggestion. `class` a keyword in ***Ruby***.

Comment: crap. `class` was creating problems. Thanks @Dave, and post that as an answer. I will vote up and tag solved :D

P.S. Rails ain't exactly programming but it still uses class a a keyword

Comment: @Ryzokuken I've been coding rails for 5 years, it is, exactly, programming. What you're currently doing, using a scaffold to create a completely generic CRUD app, is just using a script, but please don't think that's the end of it's capabilities.

Comment: @AJFaraday thanks for the advice sir, ill keep it in mind. :D

Comment: I'd advise you to stop using `rails g scaffold` and stick to more specific generators like `rails g model` because if you think that Rails is not programming you are clearly missing stuff that happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` is a keyword in Ruby, so using that as a column name isn't a great idea. On this line:

`$ rails generate scaffold student name:string id_number:integer class:integer section:string issued:date returned:date fine:integer reissued:date`

change `class:integer` to `kind:integer` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm :D 
Too stupid of me not to notice that, but maybe coding(HTML/CSS) has taken its toll on me